# Fedora Core 11 on VMWare ESX

Tags: fedora, vmware-esx

I'm trying to install Fedora Core 11 on a VMWare ESX server and am having trouble at the disk partitioning stage. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the configuration, but when the installer tries to partition the disk, it can't.

Sorry I don't have the exact error message here; I'm passing along what my system administrator is telling me. I'll try to get the error and update this question.

In the meantime, is this a known issue with FC11 and ESX? What's the workaround?

And are there any other gotcha's?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are selecting the OS type Red Hat Enterprise 5 when creating the VM, and you will not have any issues with a recent version of VMware ESX.